Visualizing a solar eclipse in 3D in MATLAB, inhibited by near-plane clipping
I am trying to visualize a solar eclipse in MATLAB, by plotting the Sun and Moon as spheres and placing the camera at the position of the earth, lining everything up along the x-axis for simplicity.  It appears that when I try to use the correct distances, the Moon is not rendered.  This happens, as far as I can tell, due to near-plane clipping.  Is there a solution to this, so that more generally, relatively small objects very close to the camera can be visualized?
Here is what the code currently produces, with the camera moved further away from the sun so that the Moon is indeed rendered:

But when I try to move the camera closer the moon disappears.
MATLAB code to reproduce the problem:
% Define sizes/positions of sun, earth, moon, with the camera on earth
sunRadius         = 696340;                            % Sun radius in km
moonRadius        = 1737;                              % Moon radius in km
earthPosition     = 149600000;                         % Distance from Sun center to Earth center (1 AU)
earthMoonDistance = 384400;                            % Distance from Earth to Moon (in km)
moonPosition      = earthPosition - earthMoonDistance; % Moon position relative to Sun

% Move camera just a little further away from the moon to avoid near-plane clipping
camPosition  = earthPosition*1.01; 
% If we put the camera right at the earth, the moon is not rendered due to near-plane clipping:
% camPosition  = earthPosition;

% Plot Sun and Moon as spheres, and set camera position
figure;
set(gcf, 'WindowState', 'maximized')

hold on;
axis equal;
% Configure lighting for better visualization
lighting phong;
light('Position', [1 1 1], 'Style', 'infinite');

% Plot the Sun (yellow sphere) at the origin
[x_sun, y_sun, z_sun] = sphere(50);
sun = surf(sunRadius * x_sun, ...
           sunRadius * y_sun, ...
           sunRadius * z_sun);
set(sun, 'FaceColor', [1, 1, 0], 'EdgeColor', 'none');

% Plot the Moon (grey sphere) relative to the Sun
[x_moon, y_moon, z_moon] = sphere(50);
moon = surf(moonRadius * x_moon + moonPosition, ...
            moonRadius * y_moon, ...
            moonRadius * z_moon);
set(moon, 'FaceColor', [0.5, 0.5, 0.5], 'EdgeColor', 'none');

% Set up camera properties relative to the Sun
camproj('perspective')
campos([camPosition, 0,0]); % Camera at approximately
camtarget([camPosition-1, 0, 0]); % Camera looking down the x-axis towards the origin
camva(1); % Set camera view angle small enough to zoom in on eclipse

EDIT:
As @Edric answered, axis tight fixes the problem as stated.  However, this only works because in the original problem everything was aligned along the x-axis, and axis tight significantly reduces the volume of the 3D plot.  However, if we align everything along the vector [1,1,1] then the problem persists even with axis tight:
% Define sizes/positions of sun, earth, moon, with the camera on earth
sunRadius         = 696340;                            % Sun radius in km
moonRadius        = 1737;                              % Moon radius in km
earthDistance     = 149600000;                         % Distance from Sun center to Earth center (1 AU)
earthMoonDistance = 384400;                            % Distance from Earth to Moon (in km)
moonDistance      = earthDistance - earthMoonDistance; % Moon position relative to Sun

directionVector = [1,1,1];
directionVector = directionVector/norm(directionVector);

% Move camera just a little further away from the moon to avoid near-plane clipping
camPosition  = earthDistance*1.004*directionVector;
moonPosition = moonDistance*directionVector;
earthPosition = earthDistance*directionVector;
% If we put the camera right at the earth, the moon is not rendered due to near-plane clipping:
% camPosition  = earthPosition;

% Plot Sun and Moon as spheres, and set camera position
figure;
set(gcf, 'WindowState', 'maximized')

hold on;
axis equal;
% Configure lighting for better visualization
lighting phong;
light('Position', [1 1 1], 'Style', 'infinite');

% Plot the Sun (yellow sphere) at the origin
[x_sun, y_sun, z_sun] = sphere(50);
sun = surf(sunRadius * x_sun, ...
           sunRadius * y_sun, ...
           sunRadius * z_sun);
set(sun, 'FaceColor', [1, 1, 0], 'EdgeColor', 'none');

% Plot the Moon (grey sphere) relative to the Sun
[x_moon, y_moon, z_moon] = sphere(50);
moon = surf(moonRadius * x_moon + moonPosition(1), ...
            moonRadius * y_moon + moonPosition(2), ...
            moonRadius * z_moon + moonPosition(3));
set(moon, 'FaceColor', [0.5, 0.5, 0.5], 'EdgeColor', 'none');

% Set up camera properties relative to the Sun
camproj('perspective')
campos(camPosition); % Camera at approximately
camtarget([0, 0, 0]); % Camera looking down the x-axis towards the origin
camva(1); % Set camera view angle small enough to zoom in on eclipse
axis tight


I think you can fix this by scoping down the axis range. The simplest fix is to run
axis tight



That fixes it!  But why?

Actually this only fixes it because we are aligned along the x-axis, so axis tight significantly reduces the total volume of the plot.  However, if we align the moon and the camera with the vector [1,1,1] we end up with the same problem and axis tight cannot fix it

Sorry, I don't really know what I'm doing - I read just enough to learn that scoping the axis down can help modify the viewing frustrum.
